# executeQueryAsync working fine in IE problem in firefox not calling on asp button client click

Tags: spservices

```
 function updatefeeall() {    
        var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        currentweb = ctx.get_web();
        this.list = currentweb.get_lists().getByTitle("ClubFeePattern");

        var query = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
        this.allItems = list.getItems(query);
        ctx.load(allItems, 'Include(Title,Years,Amount,ID)');
        ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.ExecuteOngetallSuccess),
                                   Function.createDelegate(this, this.ExecuteOngetallFailure));
    }
```

function OnValidate() {

```
    var chkAutoApproval = document.getElementById("<%=chkAutoApproval.ClientID %>");
    var txtSiteAccessToken = document.getElementById("<%=txtSiteAccessToken.ClientID %>");
    var txtSiteAccountId = document.getElementById("<%=txtSiteAccountId.ClientID %>");
    var accountTR = document.getElementById("<%= accountTR.ClientID %>");
    var ddlCategory = document.getElementById('<%=ddlClubCategory.ClientID%>');

    if (ddlCategory.options[ddlCategory.selectedIndex].value == '-- Select Club Category --') {
        alert("Please select the Category");
        return false;
    }

    if (chkAutoApproval.checked) {

        accountTR.style.visibility = "hidden";
        return true;
    }
    else {

        var valtxtSiteAccessToken = txtSiteAccessToken.value;
        var valtxtSiteAccountId = txtSiteAccountId.value;

        if ((valtxtSiteAccessToken != '' || valtxtSiteAccessToken.length > 0) && txtSiteAccountId.value == '') {
            alert("Please enter the WePay AccountID.");
            return false;
        }
        if (txtSiteAccessToken.value == '' && txtSiteAccountId.value != '') {

            alert("Please enter the WePay AccessToken.");
            return false;
        }


    }
    return updatefeeall();
}
```

Comment: How do you bind handler for button?

Comment: here is  my code <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" OnClientClick="return OnValidate();" CssClass="buttongroup" Width="80px" Text="Save"
        OnClick="btnSave_Click" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="Submit" />

Comment: how do you invoke updatefeeall function?

Comment: in OnValidate function i am calling the updatefeeall() method

Comment: In IE its working fine problem in other major browsers

Comment: if i'm not wrong your OnValidate function should return false or true, but, if you use 'return updatefeell' it does not return boolean value.

Comment: On ExecuteOngetallSuccess method i am returning true on Failure returning false

Comment: but this action is async, so your updatefeell function does not return any value. It doesn't wait ExecuteOngetallSucccess

Comment: ya IE is waiting for that method to execute but why other browsers not

Comment: I do not know how IE works in this case, but I'm sure that it does not wait too.

Comment: what to do any idea

Comment: is there any way to call that method sync from javascript

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6838/discussion-between-alexander-and-rajesh-chowdary)